# How can I change language names to short names in qtranslate (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I am using the qtranslate plugin in wordpress.

Right now the languages on my page are displayed like this: ENGLISH DEUTSCH

I wish them to be displayed like this: EN DE

I was searching in the plugin folder but couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in admin Dashboard menu go to
**Settings > Languages > Default Language / Order**

There is you can change the short names for your languages chooses, as well as a prefix to the URL.